# Finding average file size in MB in given directory

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to display the average file size in MB of given directory.

I started coding like this

```
string filePath = @"DesiredFilePath";
var getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
var length = getFiles.Select(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
```

how to extend the code to find average file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost near.

Try this

```
string filePath = @"DesiredFilePath";
           var getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
           var avg = getFiles.Select(f =>
                           new FileInfo(f).Length).Average();

           Console.WriteLine("The Average file size in {0} directory is {1} MB",
            filePath,Math.Round(avg/1048576,1));
```

Comment: Hm... "almost near", I'm gonna steal that sometime. ;)

Comment: Hmmm... last time I checked 1 MB was not 1000000 bytes :)

Comment: @ Erno de Weered - Thanks i have edited my answer ,i guess 1 MB = 1048576 bytes. Correct me if i am wrong. :)

Comment: @Erno: There is no universal agreement on the number of bytes in a MB. It can be 1,000 x 1,000 (10^6) bytes, 1,000 x 1,024 bytes, or 1,024 x 1,024 (2^20) bytes. Thus the unambiguous 'MiB' unit was introduced; see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: @stakx - Thanks for the interesting reference! I suppose I am a IEC adept then :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) extension method:

```
// using System.Linq;
string filePath = @"DesiredFilePath";
double averageFileSize = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(filePath)
    .Average(x => new FileInfo(x).Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It think this is the shortest way (less code) to do it:

```
string filePath = "My Path";
double averageBytes = new DirectoryInfo(filePath)
    .EnumerateFiles()
    .Average(file => file.Length);
double averageMb = averageBytes / 1048576.0;
```